# My music and videos are splitting not playing the sound correctly

Tags: windows-7, audio, video, vlc-media-player

My laptop configuration is **corei5, 8 gb ram, Windows 7 professional**. When i tried to play a music in media player or play a video in vlc in both cases the music of video starts freezing for some time.
some time it happens that the video keep playing but the music starts from last 5 sec. i dnt knw what the hack is this.

Usage - Idle, also happens in case of only playing songs or videos

Anti Virus - Macafee

Comment: There isn't a lot of information given in the question. It may not get a lot of answers since people don't have a lot of valuable information here. Some good information might be; what type of anti-virus are you using, is the computer under a heavy load while this is happening, are you running other resource intense programs at the same time, etc.

Comment: @David This is mainly happens when i used to play only vlc or media player. no other program is running. sometime i used to run **Visual Studio** and the antivirus is MacAfee

Comment: Is this a constant problem or does it only happen sometimes? I really don't trust McAfee by any stretch. Any good, experienced, seasoned techs will agree with me on that. I have had MANY encounters where McAfee has caused horrible problems on client machines at the data center I work at as well as free lancing projects. A test to see if McAfee is causing you issues would be to first, disconnect yourself from the internet to prevent you from accidentally installing a virus, then completely stop McAfee (no services or processes running), then try playing the videos.

Comment: @David Thanks for the help . I'll try that. Thank You so much . :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please post back if this fixes the issue. If it does, I will try to tailor up an answer that is less opinionated about McAfee being awful AV so you can accept that answer to help distinguish what exactly fixed your problem.

Comment: @David You can post your answer. The AV and driver update was the reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest disabling and killing all AV processes for a text. I know from experience that McAfee can cause many issues with all operating systems. McAfee is constantly scanning files that are being used, which could cause latency, or in your case, lagg when watching a video, while using a known good media player.